# Automatically call HTMLBeaufity when exiting Insert mode in Vim

Tags: autocmd, plugin-vim-jsbeautify

I'd like to automatically format html and js code when I exit insert mode. Currently I have <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> mapped to format the current file in my `.vimrc`:

```
map <c-f> :call JSBeautify()<cr>
```

Is there a way I can trigger this command each time I exit insert mode?

Comment: Really ? *Each* time you leave insert mode?

Comment: @romainl I guess it's a quick way to tidy things up. For example, if I paste code into vim from my system clipboard the formatting may not be quite right

Comment: @alidrongo Note that to paste code from your system to vim you are not necessarily in insert mode (e.g. `"+p` in normal mode). A solution could be to trigger the command only when you write the buffer to the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`InsertLeave`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#InsertLeave) autocommand event to do what you want. You can add something like that in your `.vimrc` to create commands for html and js files:

```
autocmd! InsertLeave *.html,*.js call JSBeautify
```

- `InsertLeave` will trigger the event each time you exit insert mode.
- `*.html,*.js` to do that only on html and js files.
- `call JSBeautify` is the call you want to do.

Also you could be interested in the [`BufWritePre`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufWritePre) event which will trigger the command just before writing the buffer to the file. Using the command each time you leave insert mode may be not that comfortable I think.

Relevant help topic:

- [`:h autocmd-events`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#autocmd-events)

**Edit** In the comments OP asks how to use different function for different filetypes. The easiest solution I see is using an `augroup`:

```
augroup
    autocmd!
    autocmd! InsertLeave *.js   call JSBeautify
    autocmd! InsertLeave *.html call HTMLBeautify
    autocmd! InsertLeave *.css  call CSSBeautify
augroup END
```

- `augroup` allows to group autocommands.
- `autocmd!` purges the group when you need to re-source your `.vimrc`
- the 3 autocommands are pretty similar to the first one excepted they are triggered for only one filetype.

More related topics:

- [`:h :augroup`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#:augroup)
- [LearnVimscriptTheHardWay chapter on `augroup`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html) *(Also all of this book is pretty good to learn vimscript so don't hesitate to read all of it ;-) )*

Comment: Great stuff. One further question (I'm pretty early on my vim journey): I have some logic that selects the kind of beautification based on the file type:
 `map <c-f> :call JsBeautify()<cr>
" or
autocmd FileType javascript noremap <buffer>  <c-f> :call JsBeautify()<cr>
" for html
autocmd FileType html noremap <buffer> <c-f> :call HtmlBeautify()<cr>
" for css or scss
autocmd FileType css noremap <buffer> <c-f> :call CSSBeautify()<cr>
`    Is there a way I can do this also automatically? Many thanks!

Comment: @alidrongo: I edited my answer I think the best way to do what you want is to use an `augroup` containing one autocommand by function to call.